# 'hate to' vs '{synonym of hate} to'

Tags: word-usage, difference

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dislike+to%2Chate+to%2Cloathe+to&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdislike%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chate%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cloathe%20to%3B%2Cc0) displays the prominence of only **hate to**, but why so? Why are the others (eg **dislike to**, **loathe to**) rarer? Are they all grammatically correct? Excepting the degree of dislike, what are the differences?

I did read [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/173037/50720) but the lack of upvotes worries me.

Comment: "loath to" (based on the adjective form) is [used fairly often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dislike+to%2Chate+to%2Cloathe+to%2Cloath+to&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdislike%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chate%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cloathe%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cloath%20to%3B%2Cc0) (relative to "hate to"'s usage).  For example, "He is loath to renege on his pledges."

Answer (score 1):

There is an antonym which follows the construction - "love to".  Otherwise, ordinary usage suggests the construction, for instance, of "I loathe doing homework", "I dislike getting wet" or "I enjoy getting drunk".

The only intermediate term I can think of is "like", which can often be found in either construction. "I like staying up late" is just as acceptable as "I like to stay up late".

EDIT - The above is wrong. Having slept on it, I realized that both "hate to" and "love to" behave exactly the way "like to" does. All three can use both forms (with or without the "to") while the other terms are restricted to the form without the "to".

So you can say "I love sleeping late" and "I love to sleep late", or "I hate getting my feet wet" and "I hate to get my feet wet", but you can't say "I loathe to get my feet wet", or "I enjoy to sleep late".

Sorry for the error.